# Can not call newly picked date/time data from outside of function

Tags: react-native

The function DateTimePick below works well and render any date/time that user selected on screen. const date, mode, show were set state to new ones via useState all good.

Here is the problem: I expect that if I call DateTimePick.date from outside (to use this data in another function/class), I will receive DateTimePick.date for last state, i.e. the date data that just has been picked and rendered. However what I receive was DateTimePick.date for initial state which is date: new Date()

Any ideas why? Thanks

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Button, Platform, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import Moment from "moment";

export const DateTimePick = () => {  
  
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
      const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
      setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
      setDate(currentDate);
  };
  
  const showMode = (currentMode) => {
      setShow(true);
      setMode(currentMode);
  };
  
  const showDatepicker = () => {
      showMode('date');
  };
  
  const showTimepicker = () => {
      showMode('time');
  };
    
      return (
      <View>                
          <View style={styles.formRow}>
              <Text style={styles.formLabel}> Date</Text>
              <Text onPress={showDatepicker} style={styles.formItem} value_date={date.toDateString()} onChange = {(value_date) => this.props.setState({date: value_date})}><Icon type='font-awesome-5' name='calendar' color='#512DA8' />{' ' + Moment(date).format('DD-MMM-YYYY') }</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.formRow}>
              <Text style={styles.formLabel}> Time</Text>
              <Text onPress={showTimepicker} style={styles.formItem} value_time={date.toTimeString()} onChange = {(value_time) => this.props.setState({time: value_time})}><Icon type='font-awesome-5' name='clock' color='#512DA8' /> {' ' + Moment(date).format('h:mm A') }</Text>
          </View>
          {show && (
          <DateTimePicker
              testID="dateTimePicker"
              value={date}
              mode={mode}
              is24Hour={true}
              display="default"
              onChange={onChange}
          />
          )}        
      </View>
      );
  };

//export default DateTimePick;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  formRow: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      margin: 20
  },
  formLabel: {
      fontSize: 18,
      flex: 1
  },
  formItem: {
      flex: 1        
  },
  modal: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      margin: 20
  },
  modalTitle: {
      fontSize: 24,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: 'white',
      marginBottom: 20
  },
  modalText: {
      fontSize: 18,
      margin: 10
  },
})
```

Comment: my guess is that the children rerender, but not the parent component.

Comment: Scratching my ears on this prob. To test I extract and print value of 'date' inside function DateTimePick, the print updates new value well for every new date n time pick. It means last state is recorded and rendered well. Can not see what trigger it to return to initial state when calling from outside of the function.

Comment: how do you call `DateTimePicker.date` in you parent component? My guess is that it just called it once on mounting, then when the date change in DateTimePicker, the only component that rerender is DateTimePicker not your parent component hence the parent component only have the initial state

Comment: Here what I called in parent in order ```<DateTimePick />

                <Text>{Moment(DateTimePick.date).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')} {Moment(DateTimePick.date).format('h:mm A')}</Text>
```

Comment: the ```<DateTimePick />``` popup the date selector and time selector, I selected new date/ time and these new date and time were rendered well on screen. Then to extract the data as variable for further use, I called for DateTimePick.date as above

Comment: I never called state from other component like that so I'm not sure if it works. If it works, what you can try is to check if the parent component rerender. You can do that by calling a console.log in the parent component. It might help with your debugging. You can solve the problem by having the state in the parent component and a handler that change the state and pass them to the DateTimePick, or DateTimePick return an array of the JSX element and the date. `[Component, date]`. Then you can use the date in you parent component.

Comment: Thank you. One thing can explain this odd is when call from outside, the state of the child did not preserved, i.e. no inherit here. The program actually opens a new child and as a new child, the child state starts with default initial state as we observed.